# Exposing Service from a BareMetal(Kubeadm) Kubernetes Cluster to outside world

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, metallb

Exposing Service from a BareMetal(Kubeadm) Build Kubernetes Cluster to the outside world. I am trying to access my Nginx as a service outside of the cluster to get NGINX output in the web browser.

For that, I have created a deployment and service for NGINX as shown below, [image]

As per my search, found that we have below to expose to outside world

- MetalLb
- Ingress NGINX
- Some HELM resources

I would like to know all these 3 or any more approaches in such way it help me to learn new things.

`GOAL`

- Exposing Service from a BareMetal(Kubeadm) Built Kubernetes Cluster to the outside world.
- How Can I make my service has its own public IP to access from the outside cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up `MetalLB` to get an external IP address for the `LoadBalancer` type services. It will give a local network IP address to the service.

Then you can do port mapping (configuration in the router) of incoming traffic of port `80` and port `443` to your external service IP address.

I have done a similar setup you can check it here in detail:
https://developerdiary.me/lets-build-low-budget-aws-at-home/

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) in your cluster so that it gives you an entrypoint where your applications can be accessed. Traditionally, in a cloud native environment it would automatically provision a LoadBalancer for you that will read the rules you define inside your [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) object and route your request to the appropriate service.

One of the most commonly used ingress controller is the [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/). There are multiple ways you can use to deploy it (mainfests, helm, operators). In case of bare metal clusters, there are multiple considerations which you can read [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/deploy/baremetal.md).

MetalLB is still in beta stage so its your choice if you want to use. If you don't have a hard requirement to expose the ingress controller as a LoadBalancer, you can [expose it as a NodePort Service](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/deploy/baremetal.md#over-a-nodeport-service) that will accessible across all your nodes in the cluster. You can then map that NodePort Service in your DNS so that the ingress rules are evaluated.